# Change game attribute from pygame-menu selector onreturn

Tags: python, pygame, menu, return, global-variables

I'm creating a menu selector using pygame-menus, as explained [here](https://pygame-menu.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.1/_source/add_widgets.html?highlight=menu.add.selector#add-a-choices-list-selector). However, the `onreturn` value can only call a function, whereas I want to change the variable that defines the game mode. How can I use `onreturn` to change this variable without declaring a global variable within the called function?

Comment: Write a function that  changes the variable or use a [Lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-lambda-expr) expression.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I don't understand. Wouldn't that still require defining a variable globally within said function?

Comment: You can use a global variable or a class. However, since you want to change a global state, something needs to be global.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Probably fair. I was hoping I could maybe redirect the return value somewhere. Oh, well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since instance attributes are global, I can simply use a function to change an instance attribute rather than a variable. That way, I need not use a global variable within a function. Changing values in a dictionary also works.